# Rerouting stdout to Multiline in PySimpleGUI show inconsistent behavior

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

I have used element Multiline several times to display the output of it.

```
   [sg.Multiline(size=(55, 5), key="-multi-", reroute_stdout=True)],
]

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, finalize=True)
event, values = window.read(timeout=0)
```

I am starting a new project and this happens:

[image]

When I remove reroute_stdout=True the error disappears. It works fine in another script and no difference that would be salient, very confusing.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd
import time
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("soccer.csv")
df = df.loc[:,["home_team_name", "away_team_name", "home_team_goal_count", "away_team_goal_count"]]


data_headings = list(df.columns)
data = []

layout = [
    [sg.Table(headings=data_headings, num_rows=10, auto_size_columns=False, key='_tracker_', values=data)],
    [sg.Button("Fill up", key="-fill-"), sg.Button("Test", key="-testprint-")],
    [sg.Multiline(size=(55, 5), key="-multi-", reroute_stdout=True)],
]

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, finalize=True)
event, values = window.read(timeout=0)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "-testprint-":
        print("test")
    if event == "-fill-":
        window["_tracker_"].update(values=df.values.tolist())
    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        window.close()
        break
```

Comment: Run it well under the condition you described. Prefer more complete code to show your issue, it maybe caused by the code not shown here.

Comment: Hey I have added the full code in the bottom. It is very simple, I just started this project and I have complex code next this in a previous project and it works fine. Furthermore I found that if I close the error popup the GUI then works fine afterwards, but annoying to open with that.

Comment: Update code still work fine. Window is not finalized or method `read` not yet called, it means the window just built in PySimpleGUI architecture, not yet the GUI/tkinter built. So you will get that error popup if you do something about the GUI/tkinter action before window finalized or method `read` called. If will keep working after you close that error popup for just pass the wrong GUI/tkinter statement. `event, values = window.read(timeout=0)` is not necessary because you already set option `finalize=True` in `sg.Window`.